# Error during @angular/firebase instalation

Tags: angular, firebase, npm

When I try to install the @angular/firebase, I get the following error:

```
$ npm install --save firebase

> grpc@1.22.2 install C:\Users\aleksandr.kotov\projects\mychatapp\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.22.2 and node@10.16.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error connect ETIMEDOUT 104.28.22.74:443
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.20.22.46:443
gyp ERR! stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\\Users\\aleksandr.kotov\\projects\\mychatapp\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\aleksandr.kotov\\projects\\mychatapp\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v64"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\aleksandr.kotov\projects\mychatapp\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\aleksandr.kotov\projects\mychatapp\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\aleksandr.kotov\projects\mychatapp\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aleksandr.kotov\projects\mychatapp\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\aleksandr.kotov\\projects\\mychatapp\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\aleksandr.kotov\projects\mychatapp\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\aleksandr.kotov\projects\mychatapp\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\aleksandr.kotov\projects\mychatapp\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.22.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.22.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\aleksandr.kotov\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-01T13_33_06_937Z-debug.log
```

I found a post with the same issue on GitHub.
They advised to perform npn install grpc --verbose how ever it didn't fix anything.

Comment: I don't know what platform youre on, but try it as root user.

Windows -> open admin cmd -> `npm install firebase --save`
Unix -> `sudo npm install firebase --save`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the angular firebase package using npm i @angular/fire.
Trying using npm i firebase @angular/fire